# How to make text inside a cell in a celltable inside a DockLayoutPanel flows horizontally, rather than flows into new lines?

Tags: gwt, uibinder

Look at this picture [image]

As u saw, the text inside the cell & the the text of the button inside the cell in this celltable inside a DockLayoutPanel flow into new lines rather than flow straightly horizontally. It should be in 1 line like this `2013-09-06 14:35:29` & "`View order & pay now`". See the below code which does not work.

```
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit="PX">
        <g:center>
                <g:ScrollPanel>
                    <c:CellTable  pageSize="15" ui:field="orderListCellTable" width="100%"  />
                </g:ScrollPanel>
        </g:center>
<:DockLayoutPanel>
```

So How to make text inside a cell in a celltable inside a DockLayoutPanel flows horizontally, rather than flows into new lines?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `with="100%"` on the `CellTable`?

Comment: Yes, i did, but it's still the same.